# Powershell- read lines from file and create a sorted table

Tags: powershell

I would like to accomplish the following:

1. Utilize an API to retrieve data - complete
2. Regex the strings that I want - complete
3. Create a foreach loop to take each string and then count each string's characters (this creates 2 "columns" of data -> string name and count) - complete
4. Output the data to a nice sorted table with the highest character count on top - can't figure out

Right now I get this output:

```
String Name    Count
-----------    -----
example 1       9
example23       10
example         8
```

I would like this:

```
String Name    Count
-----------    -----
example23       10
example 1       9
example         8
```

Below is my code:

```
curl -k -X GET -H <API CALL> C:\list.txt

$scriptfile = Get-Content C:\list.txt 

$listsummaryfile = $scriptfile | 
    Select-String -Pattern '(?smi)"name":"(.*?)"' -AllMatches |
    Foreach { $_.Matches } | 
    Foreach { $_.Groups[1] } |
    Foreach { $_.Value }

foreach ($_ in $listsummaryfile ) {

    $measureObject  = $_ | Measure-Object -Character
    $count = $measureObject.Characters

    $info = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
        "String Name"= $_; Count = $count
    }

    $info
}
```

The output has all of the data, but I can't figure out how to sort it. I've tried sort-object, sort, and many other commands that I found on the web, but nothing has worked (I think it has to do with the loop and calling $info inside of it, but changing that doesn't produce all of the output). Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You just have an array of strings? Why not just sort on `Length`? No need to calculate characters. `$listsummaryfile | Sort-Object Length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as flipping to a `Foreach-Object` then piping that to sort:

```
$listsummaryfile |
    Foreach-Object {
        $measureObject  = $_ | Measure-Object -Character
        $count = $measureObject.Characters

        $info = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
            "String Name"= $_; Count = $count
        }
        $info
    } | Sort-Object -Property Count
```

Comment: Thanks Eris! I knew it'd be a simple fix. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I am wrong but I think you over-complicated your issue here. There is no need to calculate the character count of your strings as all string already have a `length` property (one is an alias).

```
PS C:\temp> "adfasdf".Length
7
```

Instead you could just use `Sort-Object` directly with a calculated property. Since it is a string and not a complex object we have to pull the actual string not the way I would expect.

```
$listsummaryfile | 
    Sort-Object Length -Desc | 
    Select-Object @{name="string name";expression={$_.psobject.BaseObject}},Length
```